# Is it bad practice to use sed to pass a variable through to another script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, scripting

There are two shell scripts.

One of which is a source file *source.sh*. This source file will exist for multiple people each with their own directories.

`name = "foo"`

The main script *main.sh* runs the majority of the code.
I need to pull through the variable `name`.

`name = "foo"`

`sed -i "3i\\$name" /main.sh`

`/scripts/main.sh`

`sed -i '3d' /main.sh`

This part of the code has been written beforehand.

Is it not better practice remove sed and just write:

`/scripts/main.sh "name"` ?

This is also my first project in Bash so my expertise is limited.

Comment: Can you provide some example scripts that reproduce the situation please? It is very hard to judge without knowing exactly what is going on.

Comment: This is confusing. Do you really want to edit `/main.sh` when you use `sed -i`? Also `./source.sh "name"` does not set any variables in the calling shell. Putting your script in `/` is also a bad idea.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the question can be rephrased to *»Is it a good idea to auto-modify a script when I could call it with a parameter instead?«*, the answer is almost certainly »no«.

Comment: @terdon The main script needs the name of the people so it can save files to their directories.

Comment: @doneal24 Can you please explain why it is a bad idea to run scripts with / ? This is what I have seen online but again, this is my first Bash project so clarification is appreciated.

Comment: @Philippos Thank you for the answer. I was unaware if the developer beforehand had a good reason for this.

Comment: @Asteck `/` is not in the default PATH so users need to remember the location. Putting it in `/usr/local/bin` is more standard.

Comment: Can you _show a small example that reproduces the problem_? Don't describe it, actually show code so we can understand exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can rewrite the script to use parameters instead of script modifications - do so.

There are some legitimate or semi-legitimate cases when you want to modify the script:

1. The script can have too many parameters which would be inconvenient to pass in command line. In this case it can be easier to do something like

```
sed -i "s/@PARAM1@/a/" main.sh
sed -i "s/@PARAM2@/b/" main.sh
...
sed -i "s/@PARAM99999@/zzzzzzzz/" main.sh
```

But in this case it, would be better to put these parameters into a config file and just read it from the script

2. The script can be part of a huge suit of scripts. There the call to `sed` can be looped over several scripts which should share the same hardcoded value. This approach often used in various auto-generators and/or build systems.

But in this case the scripts in question are usually done in a dual way - they do read parameters in a normal fashion, but the `sed` sets the default values. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
usage() {
  echo "-a=N do something (default value @A@)"
  echo "-b=ABC do something else (default value @B@)"
}

A=@A@
B=@B@
while getopts "a:b:" par; do
  case $par in
   a) A=$OPTARG
       ;;
   b) B=$OPTARG
       ;;
    *) usage
       ;;
  esac
done
echo $A
echo $B
```

If you have multiple such scripts inside a complicated application, it could be very convenient to pass all them through a loop with `sed -i "s/@A@/somevalue" $script`. And after the initial setup of default values you would use parameters.

3. The script in question can be not a shell script and not be able to do parameters reading at all. This usually happens with scripts which are by themself are input to some tools (like `sqlplus` or `expect`) - the only really legitimate case for "`sed` is changing script"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an explicit argument, you may be looking for an environment variable. If one you can use exists, it's in the output of `env`. Otherwise, you may require your users to set a new one.

> The main script needs the name of the people so it can save files to their directories.

Sounds like `$HOME` or one of the `$XDG_*` variables:
https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html